# Connecting activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

So I am trying to open a new activity when pressing a button in android studio and I get some weird errors.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlUxo.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZxfL.png)

I know really a few things on coding I just follow youtuber tutorials

Comment: Add your code in question. From image it looks syntax error.